# Gedmo Translatable with Doctrine Paginator

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.7

I have the following query:

```
$this->qb->select('partial transporter.{id,name,transporterType,routes}')
            ->from($this->entity, 'transporter', null)
            ->addSelect('partial country.{id,name}')
            ->addSelect('partial county.{id,shortName}')
            ->leftJoin('transporter.country', 'country')
            ->leftJoin('transporter.county', 'county')
and many other selects and joins...
```

Sorting, filtering and paging works ok until I add:

```
$query->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, 'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker');
$query->setHint(\Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener::HINT_TRANSLATABLE_LOCALE, $this->locale);
```

After I add the hints for the translations, sorting stops working, and I get the following exception:

`Cannot select distinct identifiers from query with LIMIT and ORDER BY on a column from a fetch joined to-many association. Use output walkers.`

I saw a solution for using Knp Paginator, but I using the default paginator from Doctrine.

What would be the solution in my case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was simple. I just had to set outputwalkers to true.

```
$paginator = new Paginator($this->execute(), true);
$paginator->setUseOutputWalkers(true);
```